# How to prevent the user from modifying the values input ​on page

Tags: html, jquery, element

How can I prevent a user from making a modification to the value being entered into an element, say input ,
For example, if I have an input for the invoice number, I do not want the user to modify it through the web developer tools available in Internet browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and others through the (**Inspect**) feature.
I tried to hide the element but I don't want to hide it, I just want to show it and not modify it.
I used hidden, as well as for readers only, but the user can cancel the read-only feature

for example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mvrk.png)

**It is possible to use hidden but it will cause a problem for my tables I don't want to duplicate items, as I will have to create an item for the product price that is visible and another item with the same data but hidden**

Comment: If user is never going to edit it why use an `<input>` in the first place and not use text in a content element?

Comment: it cant be done, if it's in the dom, then it can be manipulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control what information the user sends to the server.

You need to perform authentication and authorization on the server.

If the server sends a request which, for example, says "Mark invoice 12345 as paid" then you need to check that the logged in user is a user who has permission to order that that particular invoice be marked as paid.

Comment: No, my brother, I only want to prevent it from being modified on the page and not sending to the server, sending to the server has other rules and methods that I am not looking for at the moment, I only want to keep the values ​​from being modified in the view only

Comment: @ebrahemb — That's also impossible. The user has complete control over what is rendered in their browser.